# detect changes in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have table with 2 columns: Revision, Value with the entries :

`+----------+-------+
| Revision | Value |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | John  |
|        2 | John  |
|        3 | James |
|        4 | James |
|        5 | John  |
+----------+-------+`

This table will be used to track changes of a certain value

I would like to get the Revision numbers for when the value changes. so for the above table it would be 1, 3, and 5.

I tried using order by but this would miss the second occurrence when the value changed from James back to John

Comment: Version of SQL-Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)

Comment: sory, no lag and lead for you then...  use row number in a CTE and self join it where a.Revision+1=b.Revision and a.Value!=b.Value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL-Server 2012+, using `LAG()` function:

```
; WITH cte AS
( SELECT Revision, Value,
         PreviousValue = LAG(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Revision)
  FROM tableX
) 
SELECT Revision, Value
FROM cte
WHERE Previousvalue <> Value
   OR PreviousValue IS NULL ;
```

SQL-Server 2005+, using window functions:

```
; WITH cte AS
( SELECT Revision, Value,
         Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Revision),
         Ln = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Revision)
  FROM tableX
) 
SELECT Revision = MIN(Revision), 
       Value
FROM cte
GROUP BY Value, (Rn-Ln) ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad570/1)**

Note that both queries do not rely on the `Revision` numbers being sequential (or even being numbers!). The answer by GoatCO is pretty good as well, if your numbers have no gaps.

Comment: In which situations would the Goat answer fail ? Also, can you suggest how gaps could occur ?

Comment: There are about 10+ different reasons for an identity (or auto- generated) column to have gaps. Rollbacks, deletions, etc...

Comment: I've added a note to my answer as such, it's an important caveat that I should have included.  In practice I almost always use `ROW_NUMBER()` as my data rarely has a useful consecutive integer value to make use of for this sort of query.

Comment: @ypercube - Will `row_number` make goat answer DB specific ? But, will that solve the problem of gaps ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @ypercube - okay, I'll say it differently then. You said that GOAT answer cannot deal with gaps. Will the use of `row_number` in his code resolve that problem ? If yes, then the only thing left to see (for me) is if other DBs have a ROW_NUMBER function. Only, if most of the major DBs do, then I would select his answer.

Comment: btw i am new and still a lot to learn, hence the questions. Thanks for patiently answering them.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is standard SQL function. May DBMS have it but not all. SQLite for example has not implemented it yet (despite they have recently added CTEs.) All major DBMS have it though (Postgres, SQL-Server, DB2, Oracle) and some others like Firebird.

Comment: @Borat Sagdiyev go ask your own question if DB compatibility is an issue for you, the OP is using SQL Server, answers here are for SQL Server

Comment: @KM. - you'd probably be the first to downvote if i asked such a question :) I think it belongs in the comments section over here.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev MySQL is the largest database program that's missing the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but there are workarounds using variables. It is in the SQL standard, but you'll find that every database deviates from the standard to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self-join and offset the Revision number:

```
SELECT a.Revision
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.Revision = b.Revision +1
WHERE a.Value <> b.Value
  OR b.Revision IS NULL
```

Outputs:

```
| REVISION |
|----------|
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        5 |
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54bdc/10/0)

Update:  As noted by others, this simplistic answer is based on revision numbers being consecutive.  The `ROW_NUMBER()` function is useful if your dataset does not have a suitable number to use in the offset self-join.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Mine is db agnostic as well :)

Comment: @ypercube - do it work in a My-SQL, Oracles etc. ? I don't think so. It use a CTE. Chenqui.

Comment: this will work as long as revision is consecutive and unique, if it is an identity any rollback will cause gaps

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Almost all DBMS nowadays have CTEs and window functions. Postgers, Oracle, DB2, even SQLite. That leaves only MySQL and Access out of the game. Check mate.

Comment: @ypercube - okay. but won't you have to go and change your Syntax to make it a DB specific ? I don't know how CTE written in other dialects. Perhaps oracle say it like this - `USING ECT...` instead of `WITH CTE`.

Comment: The syntax is the same `WITH ctename AS (...) ...` The only thing that makes my answer non-agnostic is the `alias = expression` which is SQL-Server specific. But that is trivial to change.